# How can i solve this with pigeonhole principle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are 42 students who are to share 12 computers .Each student uses exactly one computer and no computer is used by more than 6 students.Show that at least 5 computers are used by 3 or more students.

Comment: Well, is it possible that 4 computers are used by 6 students each, and the other 8 computers are used by only 2 students each?

Comment: 2 student haven't any computers and not 5 computers are used by 3 or more students

Comment: "2 students haven't any computers" – but the question says "each student uses exactly one computer".

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how the pigeonhole principle is relevant here.

Let $k$ be the number of computers used by 3 or more students. Then the number of students who can be attributed a computer is lower than 
$$6k+2(12-k) = 4k+24$$
As this number must be greater than $42$, $k$ must be greater than $5$...

[Edit]
Maybe this way : give $4$ computers six users, and put them apart. There are $18$ students left. Then give each of the $8$ remaining computers one user. Then there are $10$ users left, and only $8$ computers, so two of the last users at least must be attributed the same computer, which makes a fifth computer at least $3$ users...

Stretchy, but if you **absolutely** want to use the PP...

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly how the pigeonhole principle works